# Which proceedings template to use from ACM master article template?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, acm

I'm writing a paper for a conference which has a template requirement. They suggest the use of the new [2017 ACM Master Article Template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) and have the following requirements for the page:

1. single-space
2. 8.5" x 11"
3. two-column format
4. 10-point font
5. 1 inch margin

Which optional parameter should I provide in the `\documentclass[?]{acmart}` command. I read the instructions provided in the "acmart.pdf" file

> acmart.pdf -> Paper Size and paragraphing

but even there, I could only figure out a subset with the fields 'paperwidth=8.5", paperheight=11", and twoside=true' parameters. I now have the following options to select from:

1. acmtog
2. sigconf
3. siggraph
4. sigplan
5. sigchi

How do I know which one of these supports 10-point font and 1 inch margin with single line spacing?

Comment: did you read the pdf ? it explains which option to use with which conference...

Comment: Yes, I read the pdf and it has a table listing the different format options (Table 1). I just want to be sure about the format. From the table, it looks like I should go for `sigconf` as it is the proceedings format for all ACM conferences with a few exceptions (to which my conference doesn't belong).